# Slope from linear regression or the mean of different slopes

Tags: linear-regression, slope

I've got a question about linear regression in he form of y=mx. See the values in the link below 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aB0y.png

Here I got the mean of the slope to be 0.262 but if I do a linear regression in the form of y=mx I get a slope of the value 0.31. Why isn't the value the same?
The regression: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/njj4utvsdk

Comment: $\frac{y}{x}$ is not a measure of slope for the line. You could take the average value of differences in y values over differences in the corresponding x's. This would make more sense as an average slope. It is not the slope that arises from linear regression though.

Comment: So what would be smarter if it was an experiment. Should I the use 0.31 as my answer or 0.262. Maybe my post should instead have been:Here you can see the results of the experiment about a friction coefficient:https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV967.png
The mean of the friction coefficient becomes 0.262 but when I do a linear regression in the form of y=mx the slope is 0,31. Shouldn't it be the same? I used Fn as x values and Fd(friction force) as y values.
regression: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/njj4utvsdk